# Python interpreter couldn't find the class variable

Tags: python, multithreading, constructor, self, class-variables

I am trying to create a distributed hash table. There is a thread. But the run function in the thread cant find the sock variable which I am initializing in the constructor.

Here is the code -

```
from socket import *
from threading import *

class DHT(Thread):
    def _init_(self):
        self.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5000))
        self.sock.listen(1)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            data = conn.recv(20)
            message, port, value = data.split("-")
            if message == 'route message':
                self.route_message(port, value)
            elif message == 'check alive':
                self.check_alive(port, value)
            elif message == "new node":
                self.new_node(port, value)
            elif message == "update hash":
                self.update_hash(port, value)
            conn.close()

    def route_message(self, port, value):
        print("Routing Message")
    def check_alive(self, port, value):
        print("Checking Alive")

    def new_node(self, port, value):
        print("New Node")

    def update_hash(self, port, value):
        print("Updating Hash")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DHT().start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the first few lines as follows (those are double underscores on
both sides of `init` as RyPeck already indicated):

```
class DHT(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
       Thread.__init__(self)
       self.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

DHT get's setup by initialising the Thread object part and then its own stuff

Answer (score 1):

Init as a special method [needs two underscores](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) on each side to be run.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
```

That's why your socket isn't there. It never gets created.

All Python's [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) are always surrounded by 2 underscores. For the magic.

Comment: now it says - AttributeError: 'DHT' object has no attribute '_initialized'

Comment: You need to call `Thread.__init__()` before doing anything else in the thread.

Comment: what should I do inside Thread.__init__()?

Comment: Nothing. You just need to call Thread's init when you override it in a subclass. It's in the [Thread docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

Comment: If you have other problems, create a new question. Can't go on forever answering unrelated issues.